# unix command to replace a string with null in a csv file

Tags: shell, csv, unix, awk, command

I have a csv file with multiple headers and their corresponding records as below-

```
NA,A,B,C
$H,1,2,3
NA,D,E,F
$R,4,5,6
NA,G,H,I
$R,7,8,9
NA,J,K,L
$R,10,11,12
```

Please note the rows starting with NA are headers.  need to replace 'NA' with null.
So my expected output will be-

```
,A,B,C
$H,1,2,3
,D,E,F
$R,4,5,6
,G,H,I
$R,7,8,9
,J,K,L
$R,10,11,12
```

I have tried the below code , but did not work-

```
awk -F '|' -v OFS='|' '$1 == "NA" { $1 = "" }1' test.csv >test_n.csv
```

Comment: it's always the first line, you don't need to check the entire file, right?

Comment: Please look up FS and OFS in the awk man page and ask yourself why you're setting them to `|`. If `sed 's/NA//'` isn't all you need then [edit] your question to show `NA`s is some other contexts where you don't want them removed.

Answer (score 2):

Using a fairly simple sed:

```sh
sed 's/^NA,/,/' file

,A,B,C
$H,1,2,3
,D,E,F
$R,4,5,6
,G,H,I
$R,7,8,9
,J,K,L
$R,10,11,12
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `FS` in your code would have worked

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}$1=="NA"{$1=""}1' input_file
,A,B,C
$H,1,2,3
,D,E,F
$R,4,5,6
,G,H,I
$R,7,8,9
,J,K,L
$R,10,11,12
```